# Wordpress | Redirect Plugin | Order of entries

Tags: wordpress, plugins, redirect

I'm using the [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) for Wordpress ([GitHub](https://github.com/johngodley/redirection)), a popular Open Source plugin which allows to set redirects for a WP blog.

How does this plugin handle specific redirects (URL >> URL vs. Regex >> URL). Will the redirect entries be handled successively, i.e. do I need to start with specific redirects and move on to the regex ones?

**Example:**

```
1. old.com/foo/my-article >> new.com/foo/my-article
2. old.com/foo/.* >> new.com
```

Will the URL `old.com/foo/my-article` to `new.com/foo/my-article` or to `new.com`?

Comment: You know the easiest way to test this is just to set up those redirects and try it, right? There's no programming question here.

Comment: I believe, that it will follow the first success it finds - meaning, put your specific first, and then the fallbacks/regex ones.